# DB2/400 select * works, but count(*) does not

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I've come across a strange oddity while trying to retrieve some records for an insurance system.
It seems that the query runs when I say select *, yet it whines about a date format when I do a count(*).
A bit of background, our dates are stored as ints (yes I know it's horrid) in one of two ways. YYMMDD for years before 2000, CYYMMDD for years 1999.

1. October 21 1999 becomes 991021
2. October 21 2000 becomes 1001021.

Here is the code below, I've commented what works and the error included when it doesn't.
IBM circa 1980 is a bordello of poorly executed ideas.

```
    -- returns rows correctly
select * from mudata.hdk01
where date(to_date(to_char(A08 + 19000000, '99999999'), 'YYYYMMDD')) < '01/01/1999'
fetch first 100 rows only;

-- refuses with error
-- java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0181] Value in date, time, or timestamp string not valid.
-- Query 1 of 1, Rows read: 0, Elapsed time (seconds) - Total: 0.093, SQL query: 0.093, Reading results: 0
select count(*) from mudata.hdk01
where date(to_date(to_char(A08 + 19000000, '99999999'), 'YYYYMMDD')) < '01/01/1999'
fetch first 100 rows only;
```

Comment: You have an error in the data and that error does not appear in the 100 rows returned by the first query.

Comment: While not good, the date format chosen is at least SARGable, which means the system can still use an index to speed it up.  You're going to have to use a numeric date for the query, though.  It might be as simple as `INT(REPLACE('1999-01-01', '-', '')) - 19000000` (please always specify dates in ISO format).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the following SQL UDF:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TO_DATE_SAFE (P_DT INT)
RETURNS DATE
DETERMINISTIC
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
BEGIN
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN END;
    RETURN date(to_date(to_char(P_DT + 19000000, '99999999'), 'YYYYMMDD'));
END
```

and find the row with a value violating the rules with the following statement:

```
select A08 
from mudata.hdk01
where to_date_safe(A08) is null and A08 is not null
```

Comment: I think this is 99% there but I'm having a syntax error...

`code` Error: [SQL0104] Token <END-OF-STATEMENT> was not valid. Valid tokens: ;.
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -104
Error occurred in:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TO_DATE_SAFE (P_DT INT)
RETURNS DATE
DETERMINISTIC
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
BEGIN
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN END
`code`

Comment: You should use some other statement termination character like @ at the end of the statement and set it in your tool you are using to run it instead of the default  one (;).

Comment: Ah ha! A super subtle error. Some wise guy put in 900229. Your function caught it (I added @ as my SQL terminator as you suggested). 
There was no Feb 29th in 1990. Thank you very much. Solved!

Answer (score 3):

`select count(*)` will only return 1 row, so the `fetch first 100 rows only` has no affect.

So your first query is only reading 100 rows.

The 2nd query is reading all the rows.  Somewhere in the later rows, you've got bad data in your A08 field.

Better solution is to have a User Defined Function (UDF) that you can call to convert dates, this will allow you to handle the bad data...either returning NULL or returning some valid date.

You can roll your own UDF, or use Alan Campin's open source [iDate](https://www.think400.dk/downloads.htm)